# map is update after some seconed when zoom in or out

Tags: android, google-maps

When i zoom in or zoom out map after some second map automatically goes to default zoom position or tell if any better way to set map to get current location.Also i want to set a scrollable footer in my fragment any one have idea please help me.
here is code of map fragment

```
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap map;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    private Marker marker;

    public static HomeFragment newInstance() {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null, false);
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        return view;
    }
    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap setMap) {
        map = setMap;
        setUpMap();
    }
    public void setUpMap() {
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {       LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "buildGoogleApiClient", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "onConnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        //mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0.1F);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
     LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {   Toast.makeText(getContext(),"onConnectionSuspended",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"onConnectionFailed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastLocation = location;

        //remove previous current location Marker
        if (marker != null){
            marker.remove();
        }
        double dLatitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        double dLongitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
        marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude))
                .title("My Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude), 14));
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        //noinspection deprecation
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onLocationChanged method call periodically this is the reason. Remove this line.

`map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude), 14));`

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;

    //remove previous current location Marker
    if (marker != null){
        marker.remove();
    }
    double dLatitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
    double dLongitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
    marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude))
            .title("My Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));

}
```

Comment: after removing this line map not show my current location and marker

Comment: i want when map is open show my current position with 14 zoom level

Comment: if you want only first time zoom then use onConnected method because its call only first time.

Comment: can you tell me how to add scrollbar footer in map fragment